# How to update part of the form field when submit form ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm using ruby on rails form helper.In the form I created I have several input fields: web_update(boolean), value1(int),value2(int),value3(int)

```
  <div style="margin-left:30px">
   Load Value From Web Site  
   <%= f.check_box :load_web %>  
  </div>

   <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :value1, class: "control-label" %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :value1, class: "input-large" %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

when I set load_web to true, which means the value1-value3 field and the load_web column will be updated to database.This works fine.

But when I set load_web to false,which I want only update the load_web value in database,this form update value1-value3 fields as well,and update them as 0,while I expect it to keep its orig value.

below is the params I get when set load_web to false and update form:

```
Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"YwbqeRIjadhMlPIA9fjc0Nm66p1bcu786HhaukofykU=",
 "project_id"=>"34",
 "load_web"=>"0",
 "value1"=>0.0,
 "value2"=>0.0,
 "value3"=>0.0},
 "commit"=>"Submit",
 "id"=>"9"}
```

How can I remove value1-value3 from update according to current load_web value?
Or are there other ways to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way, you can do. You can have 2 strong parameter declarations.

```
private

def load_web_set_params
  params.permit(:load_web, :value1, :value2, :value3,..)
end

def load_web_unset_params
  params.permit(:load_web,...) # don't put value1 to value3 here
end
```

Now, Inside the controller, before update test the value of `load_web` and use the corresponding the method to update.

```
case load_web_unset_params[:load_web]
when '0' then Model.update load_web_unset_params
when '1' then Model.update load_web_set_params
end
```

Comment: Thank you!So this code should be put inside model,but how it over write default update method, so when I click submit this will be fired instead of the default update?

Comment: @Orz No need to put inside the model. You can put it inside the controller itself.

Comment: Thank you!I have found that my error appears at controller without checking value nil,convert it to number and do calculation.I add a function check nil and the update 0 problem removed!